# Pre filter woocommerce products to remove a certain category of products

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, filters

Have differing prices between offline and online using Square (woocommerce plugin) and Woocommerce.

To get around this I was considering a new category for offline and filtering them out of the website and vice versa on the export to Square. Yes there would be duplication of product but independent pricing. Is there a way to hook into the product filter over all website product queries?

I am assuming if so there would be a method for the Square plugin to hook in for the export to do the opposite way.

Which would be the best filter to hook into for Woocommerce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `pre_get_posts` hook for Woocommerce product query, but here the example is for the main query.

```
function wpse_306252_query( $query ) {
    if($query->is_main_query()) {
        $query->set( 'category__not_in', YOUR_CAT_ID);
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_306252_query' );
```

If you want the opposite of it, I think the best is to add a `SquareExport` parameter to check when you want your products.

```
function wpse_306252_query( $query ) {
    if(!isset($_REQUEST['SquareExport'])) {
        $query->set( 'category__not_in', YOUR_CAT_ID);
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_306252_query' );
```

The last one will always exclude products from `YOUR_CAT_ID`, custom queries, or main query. Hope it fit's your needs :)